# Can you change your heraldric symbol?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

In Crusader Kings 2 you could modify your dynasty's banner/heraldry. Is that still possible in Crusader Kings 3?

Comment: You mean in game or by redacting save files. Latter — yes. Former — wasn't available on start (vanilla version) in CK2 either.

Comment: @user28434 - Feel free to make that the answer if you can detail changing the save file that would be great

Comment: — https://ck3.paradoxwikis.com/Coat_of_arms_modding — that's how you do it by editing files. For answer my comment is not enough, maybe later. Btw, maybe there is a dedicated mod for Coat of Arm editing from UI already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do so in the base vanilla game.

Furthermore, even creating a Cadet Branch to your Dynasty (which generates a new Heraldric symbol + Motto combo) is culturally appropriate, but gives you no options.